# What is the name of this pattern (interface inheritance)?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dryioc

We recently had an issue in C# when working with DI containers and I wanted a clean solution, but I didn't find any resources for my approach.

We are using DryIoc heavily and whenever we need a collection of items, there is a Repository or Registry or whatever to keep the items in one place.

This approach has some downsides:

- A developer has to know where he has to register it's class.
- The registry and its purpose have to be documented
- Some objects have to be resolved by another object (Object A relies on Object B) as a feature, so almost duplicate registries or repositories and even more dependencies.

My approach is to create generic interfaces like this:

```cs
interface IBeverage { }

interface IBeverage<out T> : IBeverage where T : IBeverage{ }
```

This is quite equal to CRTP, but slightly different as I have a base interface and work solely with Interfaces. The advantage is that I have a strong hierarchy, but can use this to express Features or Meta Information without inheritance:

```cs
interface ICaffeine { }

interface ICaffeine<out T> : ICaffeine where T : ICaffeine{ }
```

Both a coffee and an energy drink are implementing both interfaces, while water only implements the first one:

```cs
class Coffee : IBeverage<Coffee>, ICaffeine<Coffee> { }

class EnergyDrink : IBeverage<EnergyDrink>, ICaffeine<EnergyDrink> { }

class Water : IBeverage<Water> { }

class CaffeineTablet : ICaffeine<CaffeineTablet> { }
```

When I now want to resolve all beverages, I can resolve with

```cs
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IBeverage>>();
```

Or all caffeine:

```cs
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICaffeine>>();
```

Now, I've changed the Interfaces a little bit more to:

```cs
interface IBeverage { }

interface IBeverage<out T> : IBeverage { }

interface ICaffeine { }

interface ICaffeine<out T> : ICaffeine { }
```

Because both interfaces are simply features and can now request them from DryIoc like this:

```cs
//Returns coffee, energy drink, and water

var allBeverages = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IBeverage>>();

//Returns coffee, energy drink, and caffeine tablet

var allCaffeine = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICaffeine>>();

//Returns coffee and energy drink

var allBeveragesWithCaffeine = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IBeverage<ICaffeine>>>();
```

I could even add a third feature or add a feature like `HotBeverage : Beverage` and it still works like a charm.

I was stunned after I found out about this feature, but how is my pattern called? I really would like to find more information about it.

Comment: Inception is happening right here ;) 
DryIoc supports the variance when resolving the collection wrappers, but I doubt that's fully relevant in this case. I still need to wrap my head around how it works here.

Comment: OK, My take 2 - Too much energy drinks and caffeine leads to the generic overdose!

Comment: @dadhi thanks for commenting. This is quite a great feature of DryIoc and I have to work out some basic rules for the team when this is allowed and best practices so this does not lead into a mess. But I figured out that covariance with generic interfaces is extremely useful when using DryIoc e.g. for applying basic options to any type, but be able to register a special options type for only one type. Maybe I'm writing a follow-up about this.

Comment: yes, please. I will read it.